# Mac: How to remove Apple Music OAuth app permissions

Tags: apple-musickit

An app ("My Special App") has Apple Music OAuth permissions to my account.

From my desktop (Apple Mac OS)... how do I remove these permissions so that Apple's MusicKit JS prompts me again for authorization?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Apple Music
- Go to the "For You" tab
- Click on the account/person icon at the top right
- Edit the "Apps With Access"

I got this information from here: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-view-remove-apps-that-have-access-to-your-apple-music-account/